# I want to be able to run the terminal in the folder that is currently open in nautilus

Tags: linux, nautilus

Currently if I have folder "/abc/def/ghz" open on Nautilus and I want to run a terminal command on that folder I have to manually open the terminal and go to that folder.

I'd like to know if there is a way to have a button or a short cut that'd allow me to open the terminal right in the desired folder.

Something like pressing CTRL ALT  and have the terminal popup in the the current folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See also.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=345153)

There is a package for that: `nautilus-open-terminal`

Install it, restart nautilus, then right click and select "open terminal".